# iPhone - improving disk bottleneck

Tags: iphone

I am designing this app and there's a section where the users are allowed to draw with their fingers. As I provide a undo for the operation, when the user starts drawing I have to quickly grab the current drawing content and store it somewhere.

I first tried to store the undo as a CGLayer and also as an image, but my app memory usage went up from 7 to 19 Mb. With 19 MB I am relatively safe, because 24 Mb appears to be the theoretical limit beyond things start to be dangerous. The problem is that I have another section of my app that requires lots of memory and if I run this, the memory peaks from 19 to 28 Mb, that is too dangerous to risk.

Then I decided to save the image on disk. To prevent the little gap that happens when the image has to be saved when the user fires TouchesBegan I refined, to the limits of sanity, the saving to disk method and now I barely don't feel any gap. I said, I barely don't feel, but I still feel a little hair gap, I would say <0.1s that takes to the line start drawing.

What I do is to fire a queue operation to manage the file saving.

Is there any other ways you guys can envision on how could this be improved?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `mmap` and `CGBitmapContextCreate` to create images that are backed by a file; the kernel will lazily page in and out parts of the file as they are needed.

Combine this with rjobidon's suggestion by snapshotting every so often and you should have a robust and speedy undo system.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have a link or a piece of code that can exemplify what are you talking about' I am not sure if I am getting the whole **picture** ... :)

Comment: Start with a blank canvas. As the user performs drawing operations, record them in a queue so they can be replayed. When the user presses undo, you clear the canvas and then replay the operations in the queue (except for the last one). When the queue gets too long, an undo operation will take a long time and this is a poor user experience.

Comment: This is where snapshotting comes in. Every n commands, you save the raw contents of the frontbuffer to disk so that the undo "replay" process can start from a partially rendered image instead of from scratch. As an optimization, I suggest using mmap as it allows you to treat a file descriptor as a memory buffer: just open a file, expand it to the size you want, seek back to the beginning, mmap, and treat the file like memory--you can even pass the address you receive to CGBitmapContextCreate and get a CGContext that writes directly to disk.

Comment: Thanks. I have not seen this comment of yours when I asked this, but reviewing it today, I see the best answer is yours. So, I've assigned yours as the official answer to my question.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to store the image as vector data, this way you could play and undo very quickly and divide by thousand times the memory used. For example you can only store:

- Gesture coordinates (x, y)
- Gesture type (touchBegan, touchEnded)
- Pen changes (color, width, effect)

You also have a canvas to render the current image.

Good luck!

Comment: This would be particularly easy to do if you leveraged Core Data to store the vector drawing operations, because you could get the undo / redo functionality almost for free while having fast persistence to disk.

Comment: Do you mean that using a database to store the vector data will be faster than storing it in arrays? Why do you say core data will give me fast persistence to disk? and a final question: wouldn't it be weird to have the vectorial data for things like erasing? I mean, imagine the user finger painting lots of lines (= points). Then it chooses the eraser and erases parts of the pixels (the pixels are not exactly the points grabbed by TouchesMoved). So, at some point after zillions of paintings and drawings he finishes drawing. At this point my database will have trillions of points and...

Comment: ... to draw the correct image I will have to redraw all sequence, like the whole history of that drawing since the canvas was blank... will this be still fast at this point?

Comment: @Digital Robot - If you need to persist lists of things to disk, there are very few situations where Core Data is not the fastest route.  Yes, for a pixel editing application you may need to flatten the image into a single raster graphic a certain number of operations back from your current one, so only the last few drawing operations could be undone / redone.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks! I will see how I can do that.

Answer (score 1):

How about doing the storing at the end of the previous operation? Then the beginning of each stroke will be instant.

You could even do it on a timer so it only saves an undo if you pause drawing for a few seconds, which would mean the undo takes them back to the previous stage of the drawing, rather than just the previous stroke, which may be desirable.

Comment: Thanks. I thought about doing something like that but in my tests the timer fired the saving at the same time I was in the middle of drawing something, so, in some cases, if you draw in a certain rhythm that by bad luck coincides in some way with the timer, you can lose parts of the drawings. It happens a few times during testing.